# Python scripting for ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy: creating a tool for finding nearest distance between points

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have been trying to write a Python script with the following utility using ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro: Taking two user-supplied point feature classes (A and B) and creating a third, polyline feature class C, that contains the lines connecting each point in feature class A to the nearest point in feature class B, while also recording the distance between the points in the layers’ properties table.

However, my code seems to work only in specific routed cases ('r'), and I don't manage to generalize my code as for use in a toolkit. Furthermore, in view of my future work with Python, how would you streamline the code and make it more effective?:

```
import arcpy, os, math

arcpy.env.workspace = r''
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

try:
    #parameters (concrete example)
    outputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #FC C (polyline)
    Points_origin = GetParameterAsText(1) #FC A (point)
    Points_destination = GetParameterAsText(2) #FC B (point)
    spatial_ref_or = arcpy.Describe(Points_origin).spatialReference
    spatial_ref_des = arcpy.Describe(Points_destination).spatialReference
    if spatial_ref_or != spatial_ref_or:
        print('Both CRS do not match. Please provide matching Points_origin and Points_destination CRS')
        input('Program will now exit, press ENTER and try again: ')
        exit()
    else:
        print('CRS match validated')
    del spatial_ref_des

except Exception as ex0:
    print('Error in the Parameters: ' + ex0.args[0])

try:
    #listing points of origin
    points_list_origin = []
    points_list_origin_cord = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Points_origin, ['OBJECTID', 'SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
        for r in cursor:
            OBJECTID = r[0]
            x1, y1 = r[1]
            points_list_origin.append(r)
            points_list_origin_cord.append([x1, y1])
    print('Registration of origin points done!')
    del x1, y1

except Exception as ex1:
    print("Error in listing points of origin: " + ex1.args[0])

try:
    #listing points of destination
    points_list_destination = []
    points_list_destination_cord = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Points_destination, ['OBJECTID', 'SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
        for r in cursor:
            OBJECTID = r[0]
            x2, y2 = r[1]
            points_list_destination.append(r)
            points_list_destination_cord.append([x2, y2])
    print('Registration of destination points done!')
    del x2, y2

except Exception as ex2:
    print("Error in listing points of destination: " + ex2.args[0])

try:
    #calculating minimunm distance and exporting it to a new list for the creation of XY file
    origin_min_list = []
    for m in range(len(points_list_origin)):
        origin_id = points_list_origin[m]
        x_cord = points_list_origin_cord[m][0]
        y_cord = points_list_origin_cord[m][1]

        min_dest_id = ''
        min_distance = math.inf

        for k in range(len(points_list_destination)):
            dest_id = points_list_destination[k]
            dest_x_cord = points_list_destination_cord[k][0]
            dest_y_cord = points_list_destination_cord[k][1]

            current_distance = math.sqrt((x_cord - dest_x_cord) ** 2 + (y_cord - dest_y_cord) ** 2)

            if current_distance < min_distance:
                min_dest_id = dest_id
                min_distance = current_distance

        origin_min_list.append([origin_id, min_dest_id, min_distance])
    print('Min. point calculation completed!')
    del origin_id, x_cord, y_cord, min_dest_id, min_distance, dest_id, dest_x_cord, dest_y_cord 

except Exception as ex5:
    print('Error calculating distance: ' + ex5.args[0])

try:
    #Creating XY table
    arcpy.CreateTable_management(arcpy.env.workspace, 'XYTable')
    arcpy.AddField_management('XYTable', 'Orig_ID', 'INTEGER')
    arcpy.AddField_management('XYTable', 'XO', 'FLOAT')
    arcpy.AddField_management('XYTable', 'YO', 'FLOAT')
    arcpy.AddField_management('XYTable', 'Dest_ID', 'INTEGER')
    arcpy.AddField_management('XYTable', 'XD', 'FLOAT')
    arcpy.AddField_management('XYTable', 'YD', 'FLOAT')
    arcpy.AddField_management('XYTable', 'Dist', 'FLOAT')
    editrows = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('XYTable', ['Orig_ID', 'XO', 'YO', 'Dest_ID', 'XD', 'YD', 'Dist'])
    for k in range(len(points_list_origin)):
               orig_id = origin_min_list[k][0][0] 
               xo = origin_min_list[k][0][1][0]
               yo = origin_min_list[k][0][1][1]
               dest_id = origin_min_list[k][1][0]
               xd = origin_min_list[k][1][1][0]
               yd = origin_min_list[k][1][1][1]
               dist = origin_min_list[k][2]
               row = [orig_id, xo, yo, dest_id, xd, yd, dist]
               editrows.insertRow(row)
    del editrows, 

except Exception as ex7:
    print('Error in creating XYTable: ' +ex7.args[0])

try:
    #turning XY table2 into output Polyline feature class
    arcpy.XYToLine_management('XYTable', outputPC, 'XO', 'YO', 'XD', 'YD', 'GEODESIC', 'Orig_ID', spatial_ref_or)
    print('Nearest Line Polyline FeatureClass generation completed successfully')
##    del orig_id, xo, yo, dest_id, xd, yd, dist 

except Exception as ex8:
    print('Error in creating NearestLine Polyline FeatureClass from XYTable: ' +ex8.args[0])

try:
    # Set the local parameters
    inFeatures = outputPC
    joinField = 'Orig_ID'
    joinTable = 'XYTable'
    fieldList = ['Dest_ID', 'Dist']
    fieldListRemove = ['XO', 'YO', 'XD', 'YD'] #'Shape_Length is a required field, and cannot have its name or alias changed 

    # Join two feature classes by the zonecode field and only carry requested fieldlists
    arcpy.JoinField_management(inFeatures, joinField, joinTable, joinField, 
                               fieldList)
    print('Tables Joined')
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(inFeatures, fieldListRemove)
    del inFeatures, joinField, joinTable, fieldList, fieldListRemove
    arcpy.Delete_management('XYTable')
    print('Tool finished running successfully!')

except Exception as ex9:
    print('Error in combining requested fields from layer, and saving: ' + ex9.args[0])
```

Comment: In my experience, using existing tools to find nearest features is faster. For example Near, Generate Near table, Spatial join (match option closest). Then use output to create the lines

Comment: I am trying to learn to do so without Near and Generate Near table, but rather work from scratch as this is part of my broader learning program that I am undertaking

Comment: What is the error or problem?, it doesn't save the output?, when it works and when not?

Comment: It does not save the (or any) output, in the 'r' that is assigned to it... though it does not raise any error what so ever in the session's reports

Comment: You appear to be setting your workspace to nothing, is that the source of your problem?

Comment: How would you set a default workspace that is not route dependant? or accessing the user's own default settings?